# Python - can a dict have a value that is a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

When using Python is it possible that a dict can have a value that is a list?

for example, a dictionary that would look like the following (see KeyName3's values):

```
{
keyName1 : value1,
keyName2: value2,
keyName3: {val1, val2, val3}
}
```

I already know that I can use 'defaultdict' however single values are (understandably) returned as a list.

The reason I ask is that my code must be generic so that the caller can retieve single key values as an item (just like from a dict key-value) and not as list (without having to specify `pop[0]` the list) - however also retrieve multiple values as a list.

If not then any suugestions would be welcome.

If someone can help then that would be great.

Thanks in Advance,

Paul

*I'm using Python 2.6 however writing scripts that must also be forward compatible with Python 3.0+.

Comment: Read here for details: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries and note if you new to python - tutorial is you the best friend

Comment: For testing simple things like this, just use the interactive mode of python.  You can experiment and find what is allowed and what is not.

Comment: @Paul Kernaghan: When you tried it, what did you observe?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes. The values in a dict can be any kind of python object. The keys can be any hashable object (which does not allow a list, but does allow a tuple).

You need to use `[]`, not `{}` to create a list:

```
{ keyName1 : value1, keyName2: value2, keyName3: [val1, val2, val3] }
```

Comment: The reason why one can use a tuple but not a list is because lists are mutable, so any calculation based on their "value" would not be idempotent (computing sense).

Comment: @geoffspear, Cool but how to get value by keyname3 and list value 2?

Comment: @Eswemenasja yourdict["keyname3"][2]

Comment: How do you unpack `keyName3` though? Such that `val1` `val2` `val3` will have `keyName3` in it?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it's possible:

```
d = {}
d["list key"] = [1,2,3]
print d
```

output:

```
{'list key': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

It definitely can have a list and any object as value but the dictionary cannot have a list as key because the list is mutable data structure and keys cannot be mutable else of what use are they.